# in Jqgrid how to show dropdown value which was updated in database by user by inline edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

below is the code, in this the dropdown selected by the user is getting updated in database, but after refreshing the page i want to to display the value from database which was selected by user previously.now after refreshing the page the cell is blank.kindly help.

```
$qr="SELECT id,`emp_id`,`emp_name`, `att_date`, `emp_join_date`, `intime`,`outtime`,`Total_Hours`,`OT Hours`,`Status` FROM `db_emp_attendance` WHERE Status='Absent' and att_date='2017-04-01'";
$q = mysql_query($qr);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
$json_data=json_encode($rows);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ui.jqgrid.css"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<table id="rowed5"></table>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var lastsel2
jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid({
datatype: "local",
height: 400,
autowidth: true,
colNames:['ID','Emp ID','Name', 'Join Date','Attendance Date', 'Time In','Time Out','Total Hours','OT Hours','Status','leave_type'],
colModel:[
{name:'id',index:'id', width:75,align:"center",key: true},
{name:'emp_id',index:'emp_id', width:75,align:"center"},
{name:'emp_name',index:'emp_name', width:150,align:"left"},
{name:'emp_join_date',index:'emp_join_date', width:150,align:"center"},
{name:'att_date',index:'att_date', width:100, align:"center"},      
{name:'intime',index:'intime', width:80,align:"center"},        
{name:'outtime',index:'outtime', width:80,align:"center"},
{name:'Total_Hours',index:'Total_Hours', width:80,align:"center"},
{name:'OT Hours',index:'OT Hours', width:80,align:"center"},
{name:'Status',index:'Status', width:150,align:"center"},
    {name:'leave_type',index:'leave_type', width:150, 
    sortable:false,editable: true,
edittype: "select",
editoptions: {
value: "SickLeave:SickLeave;DayOff:DayOff;Vacation:Vacation"}
}
],

onSelectRow: function(id){
if(id && id!==lastsel2){
jQuery('#rowed5').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel2);
jQuery('#rowed5').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
lastsel2=id;
}
},
editurl:'update.php',
    cellEdit : true,
        cellsubmit : 'remote',
        cellurl : 'update.php',
        caption: "Attendance"

});
var mydata2 =<?PHP echo $json_data;?>;
for(var i=0;i < mydata2.length;i++)
 jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid('addRowData',mydata2[i].id,mydata2[i]);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please write in all questions about jqGrid **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and **the fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old/retro jqGrid in version <=4.7). The solution of the problem can heavy depend on the choice. By the way, one should never fill the grid by calling `addRowData` in the loop. Instead of that one should use `data` parameter of jqGrid: `data: mydata2` in your case.

Comment: @Oleg, noted with thanks sir

Comment: @Oleg, sir it is version 4.14.0 free version, i have downloaded from https://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/free-jqgrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free jqGrid 4.14.0 allows to **generate** the `editoptions.value` or `editoptions.value` based on the all data of the grid. The setting in the column could looks like

```
edittype: "select",
editoptions: { generateValue: true },
stype: "select",
searchoptions: {
    sopt: ["eq", "ne"],
    generateValue: true,
    noFilterText: "Any"
}
```

If you use the filter toolbar, then the only thing, which one have to do additionally is recreating the filter toolbar by calling `destroyFilterToolbar` and `filterToolbar` methods. Editing have no such problems.

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/1/, which I referenced in the [README](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid#new-main-features-implemented-in-the-version-4140-compared-with-4136) of the version 4.14.0, demonstrates the feature. Moreover, the demo shows how one can combine the feature with [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and [select2](https://select2.github.io/).

Comment: Thank you sir for the demo, i still didnt manage to get it work

Comment: thank you sir i could manage to get it done through your advice.

Comment: sir could you please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569616/how-to-post-a-static-value-in-jqgrid-when-using-inline-edit

Comment: @davidb: Sorry, but I'm very busy now. I'll try to help you later today...