# Free jqGrid 4.14 Grouping header not formatting date custom totals not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Using free jqGrid 4.14 attempting to set up a time logging grid searched SO, github and trirand and of course google but haven't found anything that worked for me. I have most of the basic functionality working but there are a few things that I have been working on for a week now and need help on completing. An image will be attached showing what I have so far and will include my code/json. What I have not been able to accomplish is the group headers would like to put in the group date in the first column and the date for the associated days in their respective columns. The second grouping is showing the date correctly but the first shows /date with a long number. the fields are identical in properties and the way the json is brought in. Need totals both column and a summary row for each group. Because the time is entered as a string of HH:MM the custom totals are calculated converting from string to seconds summed and back to string. If the totals are over 40 hours then the color should be red. Hoping that can be done.

[image]

JSON:

```
[
    "total": 5,
    "page": 1,
    "records": 5,
    "rows": 
    {
        "CDPayCodeId": 1,
        "EndPayPeriod": "2017-05-15T00:00:00.0000000-05:00",
        "Fri": null,
        "Mon": null,
        "PersonId": 1,
        "Sat": null,
        "Sun": null,
        "Thu": null,
        "Total": null,
        "Tue": null,
        "Wed": "00:15",
        "WeekStart": "2017-04-30T00:00:00.0000000-05:00"
    }, 
    {
        "CDPayCodeId": 2,
        "EndPayPeriod": "2017-05-15T00:00:00.0000000-05:00",
        "Fri": null,
        "Mon": null,
        "PersonId": 1,
        "Sat": null,
        "Sun": null,
        "Thu": null,
        "Total": null,
        "Tue": null,
        "Wed": "06:15",
        "WeekStart": "2017-04-30T00:00:00.0000000-05:00"
    }, 
    {
        "CDPayCodeId": 1,
        "EndPayPeriod": "2017-05-15T00:00:00.0000000-05:00",
        "Fri": null,
        "Mon": "04:30",
        "PersonId": 1,
        "Sat": null,
        "Sun": null,
        "Thu": null,
        "Total": null,
        "Tue": null,
        "Wed": null,
        "WeekStart": "2017-05-14T00:00:00.0000000-05:00"
    }, 
    {
        "CDPayCodeId": 2,
        "EndPayPeriod": "2017-05-15T00:00:00.0000000-05:00",
        "Fri": null,
        "Mon": null,
        "PersonId": 1,
        "Sat": null,
        "Sun": "04:30",
        "Thu": null,
        "Total": null,
        "Tue": null,
        "Wed": null,


"WeekStart": "2017-05-14T00:00:00.0000000-05:00"
}, 
{
    "CDPayCodeId": 3,
    "EndPayPeriod": "2017-05-15T00:00:00.0000000-05:00",
    "Fri": null,
    "Mon": "04:30",
    "PersonId": 1,
    "Sat": null,
    "Sun": null,
    "Thu": null,
    "Total": null,
    "Tue": null,
    "Wed": null,
    "WeekStart": "2017-05-14T00:00:00.0000000-05:00"
}
```

]

HTML

```
<table id="TimesheetGrid"></table>
<script>
    var PCList = '@ViewBag.PCList'
    var selectedId = '@ViewBag.PId'
</script>
```

JS Code

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var $grid = $("#TimesheetGrid"), recreateFilterToolbar = function () { $(this).jqGrid("destroyFilterToolbar").jqGrid("filterToolbar"); };

    var editSettings = {
        //recreateForm:true,
        jqModal: false,
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        savekey: [true, 13],
        closeAfterEdit: true
    };
    var addSettings = {
        //recreateForm:true,
        jqModal: false,
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        savekey: [true, 13],
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true
    };
    var delSettings = {
        jqModal: false,
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        savekey: [true, 13],
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true
    };
    var inLineNaveSettings = {
        add: true,
        addtext: 'Inline',
        addtitle: 'Add new record inline',
        edit: false
    };

    function SecondsFromTime(time) {
        var timeParts = time.match(/(\d{2}):(\d{2})/);
        if (timeParts !== null) {
            var timeUntil = moment.duration({
                hours: timeParts[1],
                minutes: timeParts[2],
            });
            var timeSeconds = timeUntil.as('seconds');
            return timeSeconds;
        }
    }

    function calcTotal(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        //var time = '12d 00:57:30';
        var secs = 0;
        var timeParts = '';
        for (var x = 1; x < 8; x++) {
            if (x === 1 && rowObject.Sun !== null) { secs = SecondsFromTime(rowObject.Sun); }
            else if (x === 2 && rowObject.Mon !== null) { secs += SecondsFromTime(rowObject.Mon); }
            else if (x === 3 && rowObject.Tue !== null) { secs += SecondsFromTime(rowObject.Tue); }
            else if (x === 4 && rowObject.Wed !== null) { secs += SecondsFromTime(rowObject.Wed); }
            else if (x === 5 && rowObject.Thu !== null) { secs += SecondsFromTime(rowObject.Thu); }
            else if (x === 6 && rowObject.Fri !== null) { secs += SecondsFromTime(rowObject.Fri); }
            else if (x === 7 && rowObject.Sat !== null) { secs += SecondsFromTime(rowObject.Sat); }
        }
        return moment().startOf('day').seconds(secs).format('H:mm');
    }

    $grid.jqGrid({
        autoencode: true,
        url: '/Timesheet/GetTaskList?PId=' + selectedId,
        editurl: '/Timesheet/UpdateTimesheet',
        mtype: "GET",
        caption: "Maintain Timesheet",
        datatype: 'json',
        loadonce: true,
        //colNames: ['', 'PayCodeId', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Total'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'PersonId', editable: 'hidden', hidden: true },
            { name: 'EndPayPeriod', editable: 'hidden', sorttype: "date", formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "n/j/Y" } },
            { name: 'WeekStart', editable: 'hidden', sorttype: "date", formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "n/j/Y" } },
            {
                name: 'CDPayCodeId', index: 'CDPayCodeId', label: 'Pay Code', align: "center", width: 90,
                formatter: "select", autoResizable: true, sortable: false,
                edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: PCList }
            },
            { name: 'Sun', index: 'Sun', label: 'Sun', sortable: false, width: 50, autoResizable: true, summaryType: SumDay },
            { name: 'Mon', index: 'Mon', label: 'Mon', sortable: false, width: 50, autoResizable: true, summaryType: SumDay },
            { name: 'Tue', index: 'Tue', label: 'Tue', sortable: false, width: 50, autoResizable: true, summaryType: SumDay },
            { name: 'Wed', index: 'Wed', label: 'Wed', sortable: false, width: 50, autoResizable: true, summaryType: SumDay },
            { name: 'Thu', index: 'Thu', label: 'Thu', sortable: false, width: 50, autoResizable: true, summaryType: SumDay },
            { name: 'Fri', index: 'Fri', label: 'Fri', sortable: false, width: 50, autoResizable: true, summaryType: SumDay },
            { name: 'Sat', index: 'Sat', label: 'Sat', sortable: false, width: 50, autoResizable: true, summaryType: SumDay },
            {
                name: 'Total', index: 'Total', label: 'Total', sortable: false, sidth: 70, autoResizable: true,
                formatter: calcTotal
            },
            { name: "act", template: "actions", width: 60 }
        ],
        //jsonReader: { id: "PersonId" },
        height: '100%',
        shrinkToFit: true,
        autowidth: false,
        rownumbers: false,
        autoresizeOnLoad: false,
        cmTemplate: { editable: true, autoResizable: true, align: 'right' },
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        rowNum: 10,
        autoResizing: { compact: true },
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, "10000:All"],
        viewrecords: true,
        pager: true,
        //toppager: true,
        sortname: "SortOrder",
        sortorder: "asc",
        inlineEditing: { keys: true, defaultFocusField: "PayCode", focusField: "PayCode" },
        afterAddRow: function () {
            recreateFilterToolbar.call(this);
            $(this).trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true, fromServer: true }]);
        },
        afterSetRow: function () {
            recreateFilterToolbar.call(this);
            $(this).trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true, fromServer: true }]);
        },
        afterDelRow: function () {
            recreateFilterToolbar.call(this);
            $(this).trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true, fromServer: true }]);
        },
        grouping: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ['EndPayPeriod', 'WeekStart'],
            groupOrder: ['asc', 'asc'],
            groupText: ['Pay Period {0}' , 'Week Start {0}'],
            //groupOrder [] // can use html if needed
            groupColumnShow: [false, false],
            groupDataSorted: true,
            //showSummaryOnHide: false,
            groupSummary: [true, true],
            hideFirstGroupCol: true,
            plusicon: 'fa-minus',
            minusicon: 'fa-plus'
        }
    }).jqGrid("gridResize");

    $grid.jqGrid("navGrid", {
        edit: editSettings,
        add: addSettings,
        del: delSettings,
        search: false,
        reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true },
        beforeRefresh: function () {
            alert('In beforeRefresh');
            grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
        }
    });
    $grid.jqGrid('inlineNav', inLineNaveSettings);

    $("#SelectPerson").change(function () {
        var selectedId = $("#SelectPerson").val();
        $("#TimesheetGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json', url: '/Timesheet/GetTaskList?PId=' + selectedId }).trigger('reloadGrid');
    });

    function SumDay(val, name, record) {
        if (record[name] !== "" && record[name] !== null) {
            var totalTime = SecondsFromTime(record[name]);
            var totalTimeString = moment().startOf('day').seconds(totalTime).format('H:mm');
        }
        return totalTimeString;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it would be helpful if you post **the demo**, which can be used to reproduce the code. You can use JSFiddle, for example, and [Echo service](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) of JSFiddle to simulate the requests to the server. I created the demo based on your code and the test data

The main problem of your code is ignoring the first parameter (`val` in your code) of the custom summary function `SumDay`. The value of the parameter is `""` initially and it will be **the sum of previous elements of the group**. You have to sum the value to the current value and return new sum value from the function. The fixed code could be the following:

```
function SumDay(val, name, record) {
    var totalTime, totalTimeString;
    if (record[name] !== "" && record[name] !== null) {
        totalTime = SecondsFromTime(record[name]);
        if (val !== "") {
            totalTime += SecondsFromTime(val);
        }
        totalTimeString = moment().startOf('day').seconds(totalTime).format('HH:mm');
        val = totalTimeString;
    }
    return val;
}
```

I fixed additionally `.format('H:mm')` to `.format('HH:mm')`, because you test for exactly two digits in `SecondsFromTime` (see `time.match(/(\d{2}):(\d{2})/)`).

The resulting demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ag1160e3/ displays the results like on the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edits, suggestions and code fixes. Totals are working as expected now but date on payperiod header still shows /date/(long number) should be same format as week date second group header. Also for the second group header is it possible to have column headers with the date 'm/d' for each cell? Maybe removing words week start and that date and just having the column headers with the month and day there? I have read many of your other answers which have helped me on other grids and want to express my sincere gratitude for your sharing of knowledge.

Comment: @AlbertBrennan: You are welcome! I looked in the code once more. The reason of the problem: using of many unneeded of wrong option. The property `hideFirstGroupCol: true` is the reason of the problem with missing formatting of the date in the first column. I'd recommend you additionally to use column template to reduce code duplication. See the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/ag1160e3/1/.

Comment: @Oleg sir can you please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870268/in-jqgrid-how-to-show-dropdown-value-which-was-updated-in-database-by-user-by-in

Comment: @Oleg Again you have my gratitude. I did not realize that those properties would conflict. Many different combinations have been tried commenting out properties or changing values unfortunately that was not one of them. For the last issue is it possible with your grid to do the column headers instead of the colspan on the second or even the first grouping although prefer second in this case? I imagine it can be done in jQuery but being C# is my primary language and only lesser experience in jQuery will take me some time. Hope that the grid already does it. Thanks again for sharing.

Comment: @AlbertBrennan: You are welcome! You can use `groupSummaryPos: ["header", "header"]` inside of `groupingView`, but you will have to increase the width of `CDPayCodeId` column to hold main groping information. I made for you https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ag1160e3/3/ to demonstrates two other callbacks: 1) `groupCollapse` in `groupingView` to collapse some groups and 2) `summaryFormat` callback in `colModel` (see `weekDateTemplate`), which formats the summary value.

Comment: @Oleg Thank you again. It is very close. I wanted the header to have the date (m/d) and the footer to have the totals. With your answer I should be able to adapt it to obtain it. I would up-vote the answer but don't have the points yet.

Comment: Just as a note when editing the `additionalProperties: ["PersonId"]` did not work. It sent back a 0 int to the controller/model I had to use `jsonReader: { PersonId: "PersonId" }` and the model had it populated correctly. Not sure if I was doing something incorrect but just in case someone else runs into this problem they may want to use the alternative method of passing back instead of hidden column.

Comment: @AlbertBrennan: Sorry, but I can't follow you. I think that there are exist misunderstanding about meaning of `additionalProperties`. The goal is following: every item of data (row) returned from the server should be saved locally if `loadonce: true` be used. jqGrid read **not all properties** from the items returned from the server. It read all columns, fill the values in `<td>` of the grid *and* it can read *additional properties* and saves the information locally *only in `data` items*. In the way hidden fields (as `<td>` elements) are not required. You can save *any properties of any type*

Comment: @AlbertBrennan: for example `additionalProperties` can contains some ids, which you want to save to get later. In case of subgrid scenario you can place full data for every subgrid in additional property. The additional properties will be saved only as JavaScript objects and will be not placed on the DOM. Thus saving/reading of additional properties is very quickly. It's the goal of additional properties. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/additionalProperties-option-makes-unneeded-hidden-columns-in-local-scenario).

Comment: @AlbertBrennan: One can use `additionalProperties` in many cases in the same way as columns. For example, one can sort by `additionalProperties`, one can search by additional properties. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalPropertiesAndSearchingDialog.htm), which displays the grid with *two columns*, but one saves two additional properties `taskId` and `isFinal` used in `sortname: "taskId"` (and `sortfunc`), in filters, in custom formatter and in searching dialog.

Comment: @Oleg - Yes the misunderstanding was on my part. I had noticed that you placed the id in the `additionalProperties` property early on and was removed later. I tried to research what that did but was not able to find a very clear understanding of the property. I appreciate your thoroughness and willingness to help me understand. `additionalProperties` is client-side properties and the `jsonReader` is for client to server data parameter. Thank you,